# Deletion protection for aws_dynamodb_table in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I need to avoid dynamodb table (master and replica) to be deleted. I was referring this [code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/29924/commits/0f5fbccc5dd3069f14039d7fff6c15329b1292db)

The below code only applies Deletion protection `ON` to the global master table and it does not apply to the corresponding replica table. How do I configure replica Deletion protection `ON` using terraform code mentioned below.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default" {
  name = "example"

  # ...

  deletion_protection_enabled = true

  dynamic "replica" {
    for_each = var.replica_regions

    content {
      region_name = replica.value.region_name
    }
  }
}
```

`variable.tf` has contents as

```
variable "replica_regions" {
  description = "Region names for creating replicas for a global DynamoDB table."
  type    = list(map(string))
  default = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its **not supported** as explained in that terrafom [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/30213). You would have to use `local-exec` and implement the enabling of deletion protection for the replicas yourself.

Comment: Can you please share example for this? thanks

Comment: @raj I would suggest you try doing this yourself. It all depends on your operating system, programming languages that you know and use, SDKs, etc. Then if it does not work, make new question.